# Give an example of a series such that $\sum a_n$ is convergent but $\sum a_{3n}$ is divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

Give an example of a series such that $\sum a_n$ is convergent but $\sum a_{3n}$  is divergent.

I am trying to construct an example such that $\sum a_n$ is convergent but $\lim a_{3n}$ is not zero. But I could not find such example. Give me some hints.

Comment: By "convergent" do you mean absolutely convergent, or what?

Comment: @Rwitam Jama, your point it would not be useful, since the series converges $a_n$ tends to zero, so is every subsequence.

Comment: Hint:  start with the alternating harmonic sequence, so $a_{3n}=\frac {(-1)^n}n$.  That diverges.  Now add terms to make the full sequence converge (conditionally).

Comment: @lulu  If $a_{3n} = (-1)^n/n$ then $\sum a_{3n}$ converges.

Comment: @zhw  Right, of course.  So make $a_{3n}=\frac 1n$, even simpler.

Answer (score 1):

$$1/2 + 1/2 -2/2 +1/3 +1/3 -2/3 + 1/4 + 1/4- 2/4 + 1/5 + 1/5 -2/5 + \cdots $$