# Give an example of a series $\sum a_n$ such that $\sum a_n$ is convergent but $\sum a_{3n}$ is divergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Give an example of a series $\sum a_n$ such that $\sum a_n$ is convergent but $\sum a_{3n}$ is divergent.

Here an example by zhw. is given as
$$\frac 1 2 + \frac 1 2 - \frac 2 2 + \frac 1 
 3 + \frac 1 3 − \frac 2 3 + \frac 1 4 + \frac 1 4 − \frac 2 4 + \frac 1 5 + \frac 1 5 − \frac 2 5+\cdots.$$ [Give an example of a series such that $\sum a_n$ is convergent but $\sum a_{3n}$ is divergent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2560193/give-an-example-of-a-series-such-that-sum-a-n-is-convergent-but-sum-a-3n)

But I need a better result with functional expression.

Comment: @BillO'Haran Thank you

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: How about $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(2k\pi/3)}{k}$?

Comment: @DejanGovc Elaborate it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define

$$\chi(n) = \begin{cases} 1 & n \equiv 0 \mod(3) \\ -1 & n \equiv 1 \mod(3) \\ 0 & n \equiv 2 \mod(3) \end{cases}.$$

If we let $a_n = \frac{\chi(n)}{n}$ then $a_{3n} = \frac{1}{3n}$ and $\sum a_n$ converges while $\sum a_{3n}$ diverges.

Note: another way to write this is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\chi(n)}{n} = -1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{3k} - \frac{1}{3k+1}\right)$.

Edit: $\frac{1}{3k}-\frac{1}{3k+1} = \frac{1}{3k(3k+1)}.$ Use the comparison test.

Comment: @user3228442 Nice, but how to say that ∑$a_n$ converges?

Comment: @user328442 It's $\text{\begin{cases} then type whatever your cases are (with double backslashes to make new lines),}\\\text{ then \end{cases}} $when you're done.

Comment: @Dave I’ll make the edit then. Thanks!